# How to create a new column, which tells if a value is uniquely contained in another column?

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I'm working with power query language (M) for Excel and I would like to create a new column based on a condition like:

New_column = if [Order number] is unique, 
then "1" else "0"

How can I check uniqueness with M code?

Order number is a column I have in my data set (where different order numbers appear many times depending on what production phase they are in), and I would like to create a new column with dummy values 1, 0 which tells me if a the order number in the current row is unique or not (as some only undergo one production phase).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Add an Index column
- Group by `Order Number`  (and select **Advanced**

  - Aggregate:  `Count`
  - Aggregate:  `All Rows`
- Add Conditional column

  - Something like *if the count column = 1, 1,0*
- Expand the table (all rows except for the `Order Number` which is already there
- Re-Sort by the Index column to get back into original order
- Delete the extraneous columns (probably Count and Index)